# How can I increase performance

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4, nslayoutconstraint

my app has a view that basically consists of a complex grid. There are roughly 1400 subviews. On "modern" devices the transition to this view is fairly smooth - you notice a slight delay if you are looking for it. 
On "older devices" such as an iPhone 6 the delay is more noticeable. It takes about a second or two for the screen to load.

I previously used `UIStackViews` to organise the `UIViews`, but that was too slow. Modern devices needed about a second and older ones more around 5 seconds. I changed my entire layout to only work with regular old layout constraints to achieve the speed mentioned above.

The views and constraints are all implemented in code - no storyboards here. I am not getting any warnings or errors. The views basically consist only of the views themselves with different backgrounds and the occasional label - nothing fancy like images or other render intensive objects.

I have also tried reducing the number of visual format `NSLayoutConstraints` to a bare minimum.

Is there a way for me to test which objects/views/constraints are taking the most time to render? I tried using time profiler, but was not able to detect any slow processes. Or is this basically just the baggage of so many objects?

Thanks for any tips as to where I can look
- Joseph

Comment: 1400 sub views is a lot.  Can you give more info on what you are trying to achieve.  Why do you need anything near 1400 sub views?

Comment: Yup sadly. It is like a table of colored boxes (so boxes in boxes). Roughly half are the actual information boxes (can't omit those). Then there are faux-borders I had to create (`UIViews` with 1px or 2px width constrained to specific sides) because I needed partial borders with different widths on some boxes. And the rest are labels.

Comment: Are those 1400 sub views all visible at the same time (how small are they)?  Have you considered a UICollectionView if not.

Comment: All are visible the entire time and all are visible at once - no scrolling or anything. The smaller boxes are about 10x10px on an iPhone 6. They are obviously not meant for tapping - more a visual display of information

Comment: Could you use a single UIView subclass with custom drawing code instead or something similar to that approach.

Comment: sure theoretically but is overwriting the draw method faster then using stock `UIViews`?

Comment: I'm not sure but it should eliminate a lot of the overheads involved with a UIView like layout calculations and reduce memory usage as well.  Perhaps give it a try.

Comment: I'll give it a shot...

Comment: Update the question with your results if you can as I would be interested.

Comment: Or go the whole way to a Metal or OpenGL solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autolayout is expensive. No way you can use it for such complex views.
So don't use autolayout. Don't use constraints.

Do ALL your layout code programmatically in
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
(remember to call super)
settings frames of the views.

If you don't need scrolling or interaction or rotation support you can consider to draw all that UI into bitmap, and show just bitmap. This is fastest way.